# MongoDb return filtered array elements out of one document in C#

Tags: .net, mongodb, .net-core, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I would like to filter specific array elements out of a single document.

My goal is returning a "CustomEntity" object only including arrays in "CustomLog.Logs" where LogEntity.Data is "System.string"

```
public class CustomEntity
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public LogEntity[] Logs { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class LogEntity
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
}
```

My attempt:

```
Builders<CustomEntity>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Logs,
Builders<LogEntity>.Filter.Eq(y => y.Data.DataType, "System.string"))
```

I tried to create some projections, but they just returned one array element (and i havnt got the code anymore..)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue & Concern**

From this line:

```cs
Builders<LogEntity>.Filter.Eq(y => y.Data.DataType, "System.string")
```

This is incorrect as the `Data` is a string and doesn't contain the field definition of `DataType`.

Your filter query should be as below:

```cs
FilterDefinition<CustomEntity> filter = Builders<CustomEntity>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Logs,
    Builders<LogEntity>.Filter.Eq(y => y.DataType, "System.string"));
```

---

**Solution**

To filter the matched element(s) in the array, you need the [`$filter`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator.

> MongoDB query

```
db.collection.find({
  logs: {
    $elemMatch: {
      dataType: "System.string"
    }
  }
},
{
  logs: {
    $filter: {
      input: "$logs",
      cond: {
        $eq: [
          "$$this.dataType",
          "System.string"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Demo @ MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gg9ffRUCryz)

> MongoDB .NET Driver syntax

```cs
FilterDefinition<CustomEntity> filter = Builders<CustomEntity>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.Logs,
    Builders<LogEntity>.Filter.Eq(y => y.DataType, "System.string"));

ProjectionDefinition<CustomEntity> projection =
    new BsonDocument
    {
        { "logs", new BsonDocument(
                "$filter", new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "input", "$logs" },
                    { "cond", new BsonDocument(
                        "$eq", 
                        BsonArray.Create(new string[] { "$$this.dataType", "System.string" })
                        ) 
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    };

var result = _collection.Find(filter)
    .Project<CustomEntity>(projection)
    .ToList();
```

> Demo

[image]